# setenv within script does not override value set at prompt

Tags: linux, shell-script

trying to do `setenv OMP_NUM_THREADS 8`

if at the prompt in a shell I do `setenv OMP_NUM_THREADS 4`  that is successful.  And my program runs on 4 cores if i launch it.

But I have a file called `runme` where it is only this

```
setenv OMP_NUM_THREADS 8
cd /scratch/run1
./crunch_numbers.x
```

my `crunch_numbers.x` program is parallelized with openMP and uses the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` environment variable.

Problem is crunch_numbers when run by the runme script runs on 4 cores and not 8.  the setting of OMP_NUM_THREADS within my script has no effect.
How can i make the setenv in the script effective ?

Also, my shell is /bin/tcsh.  I don't plan on using this in a bash shell.
thanks.

Comment: that is your whole script? Didn't you forgot about [Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)? Please update the question with specific information how do you run the script, with specific proof of non-working. Minimal example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you prefer using `tcsh`, your script should say so, by putting this at the beginning:

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f
```

The `#!/bin/tcsh` tells the kernel to run *that* program rather than `#/bin/sh`, and the `-f` option reminds `tcsh` not to reinitialize itself.

Further reading:

- [Argument list processing](http://www.kitebird.com/csh-tcsh-book/tcsh.html/Argument_list_processing.html) (tcsh)
- [Shebang's relation to current shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25910985/shebangs-relation-to-current-shell)